How can I recover bitcoin core wallet after encryption with password?
I have backup of wallet.dat file before I encrypted it with password. I also do know the password. I deleted my server and all thing has gone but I have back up of wallet.dat file in computer. I send some bitcoin after I encrypted the wallet. Now when I reload it it shows old addresses before encryption but not the address I sent bitcoin after I encrypted with password.
How can I recover my state of my wallet.dat file after encryption if I have:

wallet.dat file before encryption with password
password which I used to encrypt the wallet with


When you create an encrypted wallet from an unencrypted wallet, Bitcoin Core will create a fresh random seed for the encrypted wallet. It is essentially the same as creating a new wallet. This is not a deterministic process and therefore cannot be repeated by knowing the password and having the prior unencrypted wallet. If you do not have a backup of the new encrypted wallet, I’m afraid you will be unable to recover your funds.

Hi, thanks for replying. The wallet is younger and used around 2019. So, that means, I can just sync and used my old password to encrypt again with same wallet.dat file to get my money back. I can use any device for that as well?

I’m sorry, somehow I got on the wrong track when I wrote my first answer. I’m afraid that at second glance it doesn’t look promising.

Thanks! That is what I was afraid of. If that is the case then I should not bother to synchronise and use it because it will never create same wallets even if encrypted with same password used. Bad luck!
